# 403 forbidden while trying to open a webpage on a website from another website

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have hosted a static webpage on Gitlab pages. The URL of the webpage is `myname.gitlab.io`

I have another website hosted with `hostgator` which has the URL `"mysecondwebsite.com"`. `"mysecondwebsite.com"` has thousands of static html pages hosted on the various paths like `"mysecondwebsite.com/charts/folder1/1.html"`, `"mysecondwebsite.com/charts/folder1/2.html"`, `"mysecondwebsite.com/charts/folder1/3.html"` & so on.

I don't want `"mysecondwebsite.com"` to be accessible directly nor the pages in it. Hence, I've enabled hotlink protection which works as expected. Now, I also want to allow access to `"mysecondwebsite.com"` **ONLY FROM** `myname.gitlab.io`. This website has list of hyperlinks which when clicked should open anapprpriate page in  `"mysecondwebsite.com"`. To achieve this, I've entered the following in `.htaccess` file on hostgator which isn't helping. I see 403 forbidden

```
# IP to allow
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from gitlab.io
```

Current hotlink protection settings -

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW HOTLINKID:r2xGl7fjrh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysecondwebsite.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(.*|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tiff|avi|mpeg|mpg|wma|mov|zip|rar|exe|mp3|pdf|swf|psd|txt|html|htm|php)$ https://mysecondwebsite.com [R,NC]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE r2xGl7fjrh:HOTLINKID
```

I am in no way an expert with web hosting. Please could I get some help to get this working.

**UDPATED htaccess**

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://((myfirstwebsite\.com)|((www\.)?mysecondwebsite\.com))/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

**HTTP LIVE HEADER DUMP**

```
https://mysecondwebsite.com/charts/thisfolder/thisfile.html
Host: mysecondwebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Alt-Used: mysecondwebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

GET: HTTP/2.0 403 Forbidden
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
pragma: no-cache
content-type: text/html
content-length: 699
date: Wed, 06 Apr 2022 07:13:17 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
---------------------
https://mysecondwebsite.com/favicon.ico
Host: mysecondwebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Alt-Used: mysecondwebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://mysecondwebsite.com/charts/thisfolder/thisfile.html
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

GET: HTTP/3.0 404 Not Found
content-type: text/html
last-modified: Mon, 28 Mar 2022 13:48:20 GMT
etag: "999-6241bca4-dfd29bee5117e228;br"
accept-ranges: bytes
content-encoding: br
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-length: 911
date: Mon, 04 Apr 2022 10:11:14 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"
X-Firefox-Http3: h3
---------------------
```

Comment: You probably need to modify your hotlink protection. (So, your hotlink protection is blocking page URLs as well as assets?) Please edit your question to include your "hotlink protection" script. Those additional directives will indeed block "the user", since the request (when the user clicks a link) is coming from the user, not `gitlab.io`. (The server might also not be configured to resolve IP addresses anyway.)

Comment: Thank you MrWhite. I've updated the hotlink settings into the question

Comment: Right.. so I disabled hotlink protection for html & also rmoved the allow,deny block form htaccess. I get your point that the request is made form the browser which cna be from anywhere in the globe. So, the request isn't coming from gitlab.io

Comment: In this case, is there a way to achieve what I am after?

Comment: Pretty much only by checking the referrer - which is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Yes, by modifying the actual hotlink protection script (to make an exception for the `myname.gitlab.io` host in the `Referer` header), but what you've posted above is just your hosting control panel GUI. Does this not generate some `.htaccess` directives or something?

Comment: yes it does produce htaccess code. I've updated the question with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allow from gitlab.io` doesn't work on the http referer header like you seem to be expecting.  Rather it works based on the IP address of user making the request.

Instead you want to use something that checks the referer and denies access when it *doesn't* contain `myname.gitlab.io` or your own website's host name.  You can do that with `mod_rewrite` by placing the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://((myname\.gitlab\.io)|((www\.)?mysecondwebsite\.com))/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This would allow referrers from your gitlab site, and would then allow those pages to fetch further resources such as images, js, and css.  In this rule:

- `RewriteEngine on` - turns on rewrites, this needs to be specified once in your  `.htaccess` and is shared between all the rewrite rules and conditions
- `RewriteCond` - specifies a condition for the next rewrite rule
- `!` says that the following regular expression should be negated (not matched)
- `^` is the beginning of the regular expression
- `NC` is "no case" meaning that this rule is case insensitive and will work for both upper-case and lower-case input
- `RewriteRule` is the actual rule
- `.*` says that it matches all URLs (in this case the condition specified above it what matters)
- `-` means that there is no destination URL
- `F` says that it should show the "forbidden" status as opposed to redirecting or internally changing the URL.

The problem with this approach is that it will forbid some requests that actually are referred from gitlab.  Not all browsers actually send a referer header in all circumstances.

Comment: Many thanks. I've updated the question with the existing rewrite rule that is generated for the hotlink conditions. Please could you tell me where to add this in the file or maybe add your rules to the one that is already generated?

Comment: I would replace the rule that got generated and turn off hotlink protection.  Hotlink protection does the *opposite* of what you want. It *only* allows requests to your files from your site and *not* from other sites.

Comment: I've updated the question with how htaccess file looks. It's still not working... The pages containing different set of hyperlinks poinitng to "mysecondwebsite.com" have the URL of the form - https://somename.gitlab.io/charts/folderxxx/, https://somename.gitlab.io/charts/folderyyy/ & so on. Should I add anything more specific? I still see the 403 forbidden error :(

Comment: This will block all static assets on the page (since the `Referer` for these is the website itself). Personally, I think I would just keep the existing hotlink protection script (as generated by the GUI) and include a separate rule/exception before this for `<name>.gitlab.io` that prevents the hotlink protection from running for this domain. (Assuming there are no other directives in the `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: Thank you MrWhite. Please could you share what the exception rule script is that you're thinking? I'll retain the original hotlink script & add the rule you'd suggest & test

Comment: Thank you Stephen & MrWhite. I have hotlinks enabled now & also the rewrite condition from Stephen. It all works as expected. Stephen - Could you please clarify the reason for including both gitlab.io & mysecondwebsite in the rewrite condition. I thought the referrer would be just the gitlab.io website?

Comment: also please can you comment on what the rewrite rule there is doing? (Where is it redirecting the user to)

Comment: I added more explanation about what the rewrite rule does.  I didn't go into the details of the regular expression, but I can do that too if you want that info.

Comment: Thank you heaps. I am seeing strange behaviour where some URLs open the intended page while others still show 403 forbidden. I am using chrome browser

Comment: I've disabled all hotlink protection just to check. No difference.

Comment: There is nothing in this rule that would cause it to work for some URLs but not others.  It is possible that it would work for some *requests* and not others, but you would have to give me more info to help debug it such as what the referrer header is in those cases.

Comment: Hello Stephen - I don't know  how it worked yesterday. It's not working at all today. I've posted the HTTP Header traffic into the question. Also, have updated the contents of .htaccess file as of now.. Please could you take a look.

Comment: My rule is incompatible with the hot link protection.  You should either remove the hot link protection when using my rule, or go with mrwhite's solution.

Comment: I've removed the hotlink. No luck yet unfortunately :(

Comment: I would also expect a 403 error for that request you posted because there is no referer header.

Comment: Thank you. yeap pretty much end of road. sigh sigh

Comment: You could add an exception to the rule to allow requests with no referrer, but that would mean that your site is accessible if somebody visits it directly..

Comment: It struck me early this morning that the referrer not coming through is because the webpage had a "noopener noreferrer" set for all the hyperlinks !! I've gotten rid of the noreferrer & it's working as expected. Thanks a gazillion for your help. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Please could you share what the exception rule script is that you're thinking?

This is just an alternative to @StephenOstermiller's excellent answer...

You could instead keep your existing "hotlink protection" script unaltered, as generated by your control panel GUI (and make any changes through the GUI as required). But include an additional rule *before* your hotlink protection to make an exception for any domains you need to give access to.

```
# Abort early if request is coming from an "allowed" domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://myname\.gitlab\.io($|/)
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Normal hotlink-protection follows...
```

This prevents the hotlink protection from being processed when the request is coming from the allowed domain. So access is permitted.

This does assume you have no other directives that should be processed, following this rule.

Comment: Thank you. I's still not working. Please refer to my comments in the above answer.

Comment: @usert4jju7 If the HTTP headers you've added to the question are the result of clicking a link on `gitlab.io` then there is no `Referer` header being sent - that's your problem. This can be the result of `gitlab.io` setting a more restrictive `Referrer-Policy` - if that's the case then this is out of your control unfortunately. (_Aside:_ @Stephen's solution is intended to be used _instead of_ your existing hotlink protection as generated by your control panel GUI.)

Comment: Thank you MrWhite. I've removed all the hotlinks. This leaves me with just Stephen's config. Still not working. Tried different browsers. No luck still